# How to setup SearchController/SearchBar/SearchResultsController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, swift5, uisearchcontroller

So in the screen recording, I want to create a search controller/search-bar like instacart has. I created a collection-view that has a search-bar in the navigation bar (via search controller). I want to show suggested searches (like instacarts' "Popular searches") when the search-bar is selected (instead of dimming the background and showing the collection-view - like its default function). And then once the user begins typing I want to have a table view that gets filtered and the filtered data gets presented (replacing the suggested searches) - like shown in the pictures. Ultimately I'm having trouble presenting suggested searches once the search-bar is clicked and presenting a filtered table once user begins typing in the search bar. Basically I would like to be able to do what instacart accomplished here. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[Reference pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Akorv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

when you click the search bar from main category just navigate to the search suggestions.
In my case I used custom searchbar from UITextField.
I created 2 viewControllers 1 is for suggested results and other one is for showing search results.

in the searchsuggestionsVC viewDidload i am checking the character count and calling and loading suggested products in a table view as below

```
   self.searchTF.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchRecords(_ :)), for: .editingChanged)
```

create the searchRecords selecter as below

```
 func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if self.searchTF.text != "" {
          //any task to perform
          //if you want to dismiss your keyboard
        print("Pro search keyboard button tapped")
        self.proSearchQuery = self.searchTF.text ?? ""
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.proSearchQuery, forKey: "kProSearchQuery")
        print("PRO SEARCH QUERY : \(self.proSearchQuery ?? "")")
        self.navigatTo(identifier: "SearchResultsVC", animated: false)
       }
    else{
        self.showCustomToast(message: "Please type something to search")
    }
       return true
   }
```

And Used following delegates to navigate to the search results by tapping search button in the keyboard.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.searchTF.becomeFirstResponder()
   }

func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
  print("text cleared")
  return true
}
// search button execution

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if self.searchTF.text != "" {
        //any task to perform
        //if you want to dismiss your keyboard
        print("Pro search keyboard button tapped")
        self.proSearchQuery = self.searchTF.text ?? ""
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.proSearchQuery, forKey: "kProSearchQuery")
        print("PRO SEARCH QUERY : \(self.proSearchQuery ?? "")")
        self.navigatTo(identifier: "SearchResultsVC", animated: false)
       }
    else{
        self.view.makeToast("Please type something to search")
    }
       return true
   }
```

May be above code is not as per your requirements but hope you will get some Ideas on it. let me know in comments if anything not clear or add up.

Comment: Hey thanks for your response really appreciate it. I'm pretty new to swift so I feel like I don't really get how to apply your solution to make it work.